# Django: display multiple objects on a single page

Tags: python, django

I have a [lot of data](https://imgur.com/Rq4vbOY) from my fantasy basketball league displayed at index.html

When I click a player name, I am taken to that player's [single season's statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLzHi.jpg).

What I want to happen, when I click a player name, is for [all of that player's career statistics to show up](https://imgur.com/0yB6NNh), not just a single year.

What's the best method for going about doing that?  I've been stuck on this for about two weeks now, lol

Note:  each 'player' object contains a separate "game_id" that belongs to each real-life player (e.g. each player object in this list of [Aaron Brooks objects](https://imgur.com/0yB6NNh) has the same "game_id"), but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it yet!

Thanks in advance!

**Views.py:**

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'players_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Player.objects.order_by('full_name', 'season', 'team', '-ppg', 'full_name')


class PlayerView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Player
    template_name = 'polls/player.html'
```

**Models.py:**

```
class Player(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    nba_live_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    season = models.CharField(max_length=4, default='')
    team = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='') 
    pos = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='')    

    gp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    gs = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ppg = models.FloatField(default=0)
    rpg = models.FloatField(default=0)
    apg = models.FloatField(default=0)
    spg = models.FloatField(default=0)
    bpg = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

**Index.html:**

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}" />

{% if players_list %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Season</td>
            <td>Team</td>
            <td>GP</td>
            <td>GS</td>
            <td>Pos</td>
            <td>Player Name</td>
            <td>PPG</td>
            <td>RPG</td>
            <td>APG</td>
            <td>BPG</td>
            <td>SPG</td>

            <td></td>
        </tr>

    {% for player in players_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ player.season }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.team }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.gp }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.gs }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.pos }}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'polls:player' player.id %}">{{ player.full_name }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ player.ppg }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.rpg }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.apg }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.bpg }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.spg }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endif %}
```

**Player.html:**

```
<h1>{{ player.full_name }}</h1>
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>


    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Season</td>
            <td>Team</td>
            <td>GP</td>
            <td>GS</td>
            <td>Pos</td>
            <td>Player Name</td>
            <td>PPG</td>
            <td>RPG</td>
            <td>APG</td>
            <td>BPG</td>
            <td>SPG</td>

            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>{{ player.season }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.team }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.gp }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.gs }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.pos }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.full_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.ppg }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.rpg }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.apg }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.bpg }}</td>
            <td>{{ player.spg }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model structure is wrong. You need to separate out the season information into a new model, so you have Player and PlayerSeason linked by a ForeignKey. (You might also want to separate out Team too, and potentially even Season itself, but that's outside the scope of this question.)

So, PlayerSeason might look like this:

```
class PlayerSeason(models.Model):
    player = models.ForiegnKey('Player')
    team = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='') 
    pos = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='')    

    gp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    gs = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ppg = models.FloatField(default=0)
    rpg = models.FloatField(default=0)
    apg = models.FloatField(default=0)
    spg = models.FloatField(default=0)
    bpg = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

Now in the template you can iterate over all playerseasons for an individual player:

```
<h1>{{ player.full_name }}</h1>
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>


    <table>
    ...
    {% for season in player.playerseason_set.all %}
       <tr>
         <td>{{ player.gp }}</td>
         ...
       </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

You'll want to set up your admin site so that PlayerSeason can be [edited inline with Player](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin), as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply, let's see if I can figure this out, I'll have to learn about ForeignKey and this inline editing business first!

Comment: how does this bit work:  "player.playerseason_set.all"?  The object 'player' does not contain a variable called 'playerseason_set'.  I don't understand how that bit works

Comment: See the docs on [reverse relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).